# Randomly access string from array list

Tags: c#

I am working on a quiz project which also allows user to add new questions.

I have an array list in which questions are stored and retrieved for displaying. Each object saved in the array list contains 5 strings.

- Question
- Right answer
- Wrong answer 1
- Wrong answer 2
- Wrong answer 3

How can I randomly select objects from the array list to be displayed on the screen? And how can I shuffle the 4 answers (as radio buttons) so that the right answer appears at different positions each time?

```
    namespace quiz
{
    public partial class Quiz : Form
    {
        private ArrayList Questionslist;

        public Quiz(ArrayList list)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Questionslist = list;
        }

        int index = 0;
        private void Quiz_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //creating an object of class Question and copying the object at index1 from arraylist into it  
            Question q = (Question)Questionslist[index];
            //to display the contents
            lblQs.Text = q.Quest;
            radioButtonA1.Text = q.RightAnswer;
            radioButtonA2.Text = q.WrongAnswer1;
            radioButtonA3.Text = q.WrongAnswer2;
            radioButtonA4.Text = q.WrongAnswer3;            
        }

        private int Score = 0;

        private void radioButtonA1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //if checkbox is checked
            //displaying text in separate two lines on messagebox
            if (radioButtonA1.Checked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Well Done" + Environment.NewLine + "You Are Right");
                Score++;
                index++;

                if (index < Questionslist.Count)
                {
                    radioButtonA1.Checked = false;
                    radioButtonA2.Checked = false;
                    radioButtonA3.Checked = false;
                    radioButtonA4.Checked = false;
                    Quiz_Load(sender, e);
                }
                else
                {
                    index--;
                    MessageBox.Show("Quiz Finished" + Environment.NewLine + "your Score is" + Score);
                    Close();
                }
            }
        }

        private void radioButtonA2_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButtonA2.Checked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry" + Environment.NewLine + "You Are Wrong");
                Close();
            }
        }

        private void radioButtonA3_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButtonA3.Checked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry" + Environment.NewLine + "You Are Wrong");
                Close();
            }
        }

        private void radioButtonA4_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (radioButtonA4.Checked == true)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sorry" + Environment.NewLine + "You Are Wrong");
                Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is the code for class question

```
namespace quiz
{
    [Serializable()]
    public class Question : ISerializable
    {
        public String Quest;
        public String RightAnswer;
        public String WrongAnswer1;
        public String WrongAnswer2;
        public String WrongAnswer3;

        public Question()
        {
           Quest = null;
           RightAnswer=null;
           WrongAnswer1=null;
           WrongAnswer2=null;
           WrongAnswer3=null;
        }

        //serialization function
        public void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            info.AddValue("Question", Quest);
            info.AddValue("Right Answer", RightAnswer);
            info.AddValue("WrongAnswer1",WrongAnswer1);
            info.AddValue("WrongAnswer2",WrongAnswer2);
            info.AddValue("WrongAnswer3",WrongAnswer3);
        }

        //deserializaton constructor
        public Question(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
        {
            Quest = (String)info.GetValue("Question", typeof(String));
            RightAnswer=(String)info.GetValue("Right Answer",typeof(String));
            WrongAnswer1=(String)info.GetValue("WrongAnswer1",typeof(String));
            WrongAnswer2=(String)info.GetValue("WrongAnswer2",typeof(String));
            WrongAnswer3=(String)info.GetValue("WrongAnswer3",typeof(String));
        }     
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your current code look like?

Comment: Have you considered to look for `Random`?

Comment: There's really no reason to use `ArrayList` anymore, and you should structure your questions with associated answers in a class that can better describe the data model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You know which one is the 'right' answer based on the `Text` property. One approach would be to store the answers in an array and shuffle the array before assigning it to the radio buttons:

```
// You're going to make questionList a List<Question> because if you like
// Right answers you know that ArrayList is Wrong.
Question q = questionList[index];

// You should move this next bit to the Question class
string[] answers = new string[]
    {
        q.RightAnswer,
        q.WrongAnswer1,
        q.WrongAnswer2,
        q.WrongAnswer3
    };

// Using the Fisher-Yates shuffle from:
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt-in-c-sharp
Shuffle(answers);

// Ideally: question.GetShuffledAnswers()

radioButtonA1.Text = answers[0];
radioButtonA2.Text = answers[1];
radioButtonA3.Text = answers[2];
radioButtonA4.Text = answers[3];
```

Then later, all you need is a **single** radio button event handler that they all share:

```
private void radioButton_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RadioButton rb = (RadioButton)sender;
    Question q = questionList[index];

    //if checkbox is checked
    //displaying text in separate two lines on messagebox
    if (rb.Checked && q.RightAnswer == rb.Text)
    {
        // Move your code to another method
        // MessageBox.Show("Well Done" + Environment.NewLine + "You Are Right");
        UserSelectedCorrectAnswer();
    }
    else if (rb.Checked)
    {
        // They checked the radio button, but were wrong!
        // MessageBox.Show("Sorry" + Environment.NewLine + "You Are Wrong");
        UserSelectedWrongAnswer();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pick a random string from ArrayList:

```
string randomPick(ArrayList strings)
{
    return strings[random.Next(strings.Length)];
}
```

You might consider having a `Question` class. That would contain a `string Text` member for the question (because I think Question.Question is silly, Question.Text makes more sense when read). Since you *mentioned* an `ArrayList` (not because I think it's the best solution), you can have one of those as a member as well which would contain all the potential answers.

When you create a question, you can display `Question.Text`, then use the function above to randomly pick an answer. Then use `RemoveAt(index)` on the answers to ensure you don't duplicate answers.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make a `Question` class containing the question, the right answer and a list of possible answers, and have methods that return the possible answers in randomized order and compares a guess to the correct answer. It could look something like this:

```
class Question
{
    String question;
    String rightAnswer;
    List<String> possibleAnswers = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Question(String question, String answer, List<String> possibleAnswers)
    {
      this.question = question;
      this.rightAnswer = answer;
      this.possibleAnswers.addAll(possibleAnswers);
      this.possibleAnswers.add(this.rightAnswer);
    }

    public List<String> getAnswers()
    {
        Collections.shuffle(possibleAnswers);
        return possibleAnswers;
    }

    public boolean isCorrect(String answer)
    {
      return answer.equals(correctAnswer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should encapsulate all the questions in a class. For example, create a class named `Question`. This class can contain 5 variables: `String question`, `String answer1`, `String answer2`, `String answer3` and `String answer4`.

Save all your questions in a database or read them from a file and load them on the start of the program.

Use the [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class to randomly select a question and to 'shuffle'  the 4 questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that will work:

```
public List<string> Randomize(string[] numbers)
{
    List<string> randomized = new List<string>();
    List<string> original = new List<string>(numbers);
    Random r = new Random();
    while (original.Count > 0) {
        int index = r.Next(original.Count);
        randomized.Add(original[index]);
        original.RemoveAt(index);
    }

return randomized;
}
```

just adapt it to string array instead of int array

Answer (score 0):

The shuffle is probably a standard question, but I guess this will work:

```
// Warning: Not a thread-safe type.
// Will be corrupted if application is multi-threaded.
static readonly Random randomNumberGenerator = new Random();


// Returns a new sequence whose elements are
// the elements of 'inputListOrArray' in random order
public static IEnumerable<T> Shuffle<T>(IReadOnlyList<T> inputListOrArray)
{
  return GetPermutation(inputListOrArray.Count).Select(x => inputListOrArray[x]);
}
static IEnumerable<int> GetPermutation(int n)
{
  var list = Enumerable.Range(0, n).ToArray();
  for (int idx = 0; idx < n; ++idx)
  {
    int swapWith = randomNumberGenerator.Next(idx, n);
    yield return list[swapWith];
    list[swapWith] = list[idx];
  }
}
```

If you don't have `IReadOnlyList<T>` (.NET 4.5), just use `IList<T>`. The incoming object is not mutated.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all of u who answered my question.i did it this way.

```
 private void Quiz_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        displayQs();
    }

    private void displayQs()
    {
            Random _random = new Random();
            int z = _random.Next(Questions.Count);
            Question q = (Question)Questions[z];
            Qslbl.Text = q.Quest;
            DisplayAns(q, _random);
    }

    private void DisplayAns(Question q, Random _random)
    {
        int j = 0;
        int[] array = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; j <= 3; i++)
        {
            int x = _random.Next(4);
            x++;
            if (array.Contains(x))
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                array[j] = x;
                j++;
                string answer = null;
                if (j == 1)
                    answer = q.RightAnswer;
                else if (j == 2)
                    answer = q.WrongAnswer1;
                else if (j == 3)
                    answer = q.WrongAnswer2;
                else if (j == 4)
                    answer = q.WrongAnswer3;

                if (x == 1)
                    radioButton1.Text = answer;
                else if (x == 2)
                    radioButton2.Text = answer;
                else if (x == 3)
                    radioButton3.Text = answer;
                else if (x == 4)
                    radioButton4.Text = answer;
            }
        }
    }
```